# Variant of principal components analysis where only the variance of a single variable counts

Tags: pca

Principal components analysis finds the axis(/es) along which the variance of some dataset is maximized. What if I'm in a situation where I have a single dependent variable $v$ that is dependent on $n$ independent variables $v = f(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)$ and I would like to know "what principal components of $\mathbf x$ cause the most variance in $v$?" Is this an answered question already? I feel like it would be just a small modification of the PCA algorithm..

Comment: The answer is that none of the PCs of $X$ may be associated with $v.$  Ordinary least squares regression can be interpreted as finding a linear combination of columns of $x$ that maximize the correlation with $v.$

Comment: @whuber is it exactly the same problem as iterated OLS then?

Comment: @whuber also, to clarify a possible misunderstanding - by "principal components of $\mathbf x$" I do not mean the p.c.s as identified by PCA, rather I mean "set of axes that give directions that drive the most variance of $v$". This is probably related to the output of ordinary least squares regression.

Answer (score 1):

If I got your question correctly (and I am not sure), the solution is that you have to take the spectral decomposition $VDV^{T}$ where V is the orthonormal matrix of eigenvectors and D is the diagonal matrix of eigenvalues. Then you transform the set of dependent variables by multiplying the original matrix of predictors $X^{*}$  by the eigenvectors $X=X^{*}V$. Then you can regress y against the new transformer predictors X that are now uncorrelated. Since they are uncorrelated, the total explained variance of y will be the sum of variances of $\beta x$ where each x is the vector representing each column of X (so each transformed variable) and $\beta$ denotes its corresponding beta estimated at previous step. The PC variable $x^{max}$ such that $\beta^{2}_{x^{max}} Var(x^{max})$ is maximum among all the pc transformed variables is the one explaining the highest portion of the variance of $y$.